# Get page numbering & page count of a given style

Tags: memoir, page-numbering

Given a set of page styles, for example `plain` and `butter`, in the memoir class how can get the page number and count for that given style?

This seems like something that would already have been solved, but I cannot seem to find a solution that someone else has already worked out.

A simple example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\copypagestyle{butter}{plain}
\begin{document}
   \pagestyle{plain}
   Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage. % should be "1 of 2" but is "1 of 1"
   \newpage
   Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage. % should be "2 of 2" but is "1 of 1"
   \newpage
   \pagestyle{butter}
   \setcounter{page}{1}             % reset page to 1
   Page \thepage{} of \thelastpage. % correctly "1 of 1"
\end{document}
```

I gather the `lastpage` counter uses the last page of the document, being 1 in this case because we reset it.

How could one go about getting the page count of `plain` pages?

In the degenerate case where one wanted to ignore the `butter` pages in the total page count, and there are two styles, is there a simple way one could one get the count of `plain` pages? (aside perhaps from putting the `butter` pages before the `plain` ones)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could make use of the method of the `lastpage` package and write the current page number to the `.aux` file.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\copypagestyle{butter}{plain}

\makeatletter
% first arg is label for current page number.
\def\savepage#1{%
        \immediate\write\@auxout{\string
        \newlabel{#1}{{\thepage}{}}}%
}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

   \pagestyle{plain}
   % rather than \thelastpage reference via \ref
   Page \thepage{} of \ref{lastplainpage} (1st plain page)
   \newpage

   Page \thepage{} of \ref{lastplainpage} (2nd plain page)
   % save current value of page counter as "lastplainpage"
   \savepage{lastplainpage}
   \newpage

   \pagestyle{butter}
   \pagenumbering{arabic}% reset page to 1
   Page \thepage{} of \ref{lastbutterpage} (1st butter page)
   \newpage

   Page \thepage{} of \ref{lastbutterpage} (2nd butter page)
   % save current value of page counter as "lastbutterpage"
   \savepage{lastbutterpage}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks for editing to make it generic.

Comment: No problem, happy to help.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a more automated modification to [Scott H's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/76040/5764) that maintains a page style-dependent page counter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\usepackage[paperheight=12\baselineskip,paperwidth=100pt]{geometry}% http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry
\usepackage{everyshi}% http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi
\makeatletter
\EveryShipout{\stepcounter{ps@\@cur@pagestyle @lastpage}}% Increment 
\newcounter{ps@savepage}% To save the page style counter
\def\savepage#1{%
  \setcounter{ps@savepage}{\value{ps@#1@lastpage}}%
  \immediate\write\@auxout{\string
  \newlabel{ps@#1@lastpage}{{\theps@savepage}{}}}%
}
% Taken from latex.ltx/ltpage.dtx
\def\pagestyle#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ps@#1}%
    \undefinedpagestyle
    {\@nameuse{ps@#1}\gdef\@cur@pagestyle{#1}%
     \@ifundefined{c@#1@lastpage}{\newcounter{ps@#1@lastpage}\AtEndDocument{\savepage{#1}}}{}}}
\def\thispagestyle#1{%
  \@ifundefined{ps@#1}%
    \undefinedpagestyle
    {\global\@specialpagetrue\gdef\@specialstyle{#1}\gdef\@cur@pagestyle{#1}%
     \@ifundefined{c@#1@lastpage}{\newcounter{ps@#1@lastpage}\AtEndDocument{\savepage{#1}}}{}}}
\newcommand{\TheLastPage}{\ref{ps@\@cur@pagestyle @lastpage}}
\makeatother

\copypagestyle{butter}{plain}
\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{plain}
  Page \thepage{} of \TheLastPage. % "1 of 2"
  \newpage
  Page \thepage{} of \TheLastPage. % "2 of 2"
  \newpage
  \pagestyle{butter}
  \setcounter{page}{1}             % reset page to 1
  Page \thepage{} of \TheLastPage. % correctly "1 of 1"
\end{document}
```

The `\pagestyle` and `\thispagestyle` macros are redefined to

1. Create a page style-specific counter (if it's not already defined);
2. Store the currently used page style in the macro `\@cur@pagestyle` (in order to use it later); and
3. Write the page counters to the `.aux` file `\AtEndDocument`.

The page style-specific counter is incremented (stepped) at `\EveryShipout` (thanks to [`everyshi`](http://ctan.org/pkg/everyshi)). Since [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) already defines `\thelastpage`, I've defined `\TheLastPage` that does the same, this time only page style-specific.

[`geometry`](http://ctan.org/pkg/geometry) was only loaded for this example.